# How I can share cookies from my dimain to subdomain?

Tags: cookies, subdomains

I have one web site like `hello.com`, and another `world.hello.com` for example.

`world.hello.com` is not a WordPress but need sharing cookie to know if user is logged in or not.

How I can share in all subdomain the wordpress cookies when a user is logged in ?

I dont find answers so If you can tell me how to do that it could be very cool :)